# ASP.Net Web Form Emailer to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, sharepoint-server

I'm new to both ASP.Net and SharePoint development and have been tasked to convert an existing web form to a SharePoint 2013 solution. The web form is pretty straight forward; users enter line items with the option of uploading an image, once the items are added it all gets emailed to a recipient.

I was after any suggestions or best practice ideas on the best way to do this? Should it be a web part that uses grids or a page layout that uses lists, etc.

The dev environment is VS2013

Regards

Comment: If i understand you want a form, which upload the image with couple of property....why not create a list and customize the newitem form....then setup the alerts on the List so whenever anybody add the item everybody will get the email(who signed up for alerts)